# Flutter: I have changed the Dart entrypoint to Login.dart , while building apks error shows that lib\main.dart not found

Tags: flutter, dart

```
C:\flutter\flutter_windows_v1.9.1+hotfix.2-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk
Target file "lib\main.dart" not found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set an entry point like this:

```dart
flutter run --target=lib/Login.dart
flutter build apk --target=lib/Login.dart
```

[This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-multiple-targets-in-flutter-apps-vs-code-android-studio-efe7e588e0cd) shows you how to set up IDE (VSCode/AS) to build another target file.

Comment: im not having any issues with run , but im having error while building apk

Comment: build command has the same argument: `flutter build apk --target=lib/Login.dart`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be changing the entry file, you can always use the main.dart without issues and then set the Entry class there. This doesn't stop your app from working.